# Arithmetic operation on row value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with the below data

```
Tid   Did    value
------------------
1     123    100
1     234    200
2     123    323
2     234    233
```

All tids have dids as 123 and 234. So for every tid having dids 123 and 234 I want to calculate `value of did 123`/`value of did 234` * 100 i.e 100/200 * 100 
For tid 2 it will be `value of did 123`/`value of did 234` * 100 i.e 323/233 * 100

The output table will be

```
Tid   result
------------------
1     100/200 * 100
2     323/233 * 100
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

`JOIN` the "123" rows with the "234" rows:

```
select t123.tid, t123.value * 100 / t234.value
from
  (select tid, value from tablename where value = 123) t123
join
  (select tid, value from tablename where value = 234) t234
  on t123.tid = t234.tid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select tid,
       100 * sum(case when did = 123 then value end) / 
             sum(case when did = 234 then value end)
from your_table
group by tid
having sum(case when did = 234 then value end) > 0
```

Comment: In this, how to handle the divide by zero error if value of did 234 is equal to zero

Comment: What should happen then? Do you want to exclude those records from your result?

Comment: Yes I want exclude those cases I took care by adding where clause which is where value <> 0.Is it right?

Answer (score 0):

JOIN, all in ON

```
select t123.tid, t123.value * 100 / t234.value
from tablename t123
join tablename t234 on t123.tid = t234.tid and t123.did = 123 and t234.did = 234
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query. We can use inner join to achieve it.

```
SELECT T1.Tid,(T1.value/T2.value)*100 AS Result 
FROM Table_1 AS T1
INNER JOIN
Table_1 AS T2
ON (T1.Tid = T2.Tid) 
AND (T1.Did <> T2.Did) 
AND T1.Did = 123
```